# JSON input string

Tags: json, unicode

I see that JSON only accepts strings that looks like this:
Kiv\u00e1l\u00f3 magyar szerepl\u00e9s a nemzetk\u00f6zi p\u00e1rlatversenyen.

Unicode characters like á,é,ő, etc escaped with \ and ofc "/" is also escaped with \ .

My question is, how can i convert a content text to THIS ecpaed format, so my app can work with it?

Comment: You can use UTF-8 so you don't need to translate anything.

Comment: Only thing i know, if i try to parse string like "é,á,ő" etc i got an exception! So how can i work it out?

Comment: I mean, when you use UTF-8 you don't need to encode `Kiv\u00e1l\u00f3` you can just use `Kiváló`. What kind of exception you get?

Comment: Looks like i only got exception if i try to parse something like this:
"http:// myimageurl..." So i need to escape backslashes ok, and what else shoud i escape?

Other thing: All of these kind of chars: ö,ü,ó,ő,ú,é,á,ű, are a little "?" mark in my Android app. (I work on an android app i forgot to mention it sorry) How could i solve that?

Comment: As I said before, **use UTF-8** then you don't need to escape anything. Here is the full list of characters you can use http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't only accept unicode escape sequences, if you get an exception from using `á` etc then that is because you didn't encode it as UTF-8. JSON is specified to only work with UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 encodings.

Your understanding of JSON seems to come from PHP's `json_encode`, which by default uses unicode escape sequences (for compliance with javascript string syntax and ASCII safety) and escapes normal slash for anti-XSS reasons (`"</script>" becomes <\/script>"`) but neither of this is required.

If you want help with your code you should just post your code and details instead of making false assumptions.